# Best way to assign value from radio button selection

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have created this little jsbin, with the framework for my use case: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/kufijixicu/1/edit?html,js,output

What I have tried to achieve in various ways, is to be able to assign the `color` value based on the selection in the list of radio buttons. I believe there to be a simple solution to this.

The solution must also provide a way where a potential existing value is already selected in the list. So if `color` is already selected, the selected one should be checked in the list.

---

**Current solution**

My current solution may be irrelevant, but I'll post it here for context.

As mentioned, I've tried various solutions. The one I have in my application at this moment works as described, it's buggy and messy which is why I'm looking for a better solution:

The `ColorController` has an action, which is attached to what would be the `<li>` in above jsbin:

```
selectColor: function(color) {
  this.send('setColor', color);
  this.forEach(function(item) {
    item.set('isChecked', item.get('model') == color);
  });
}
```

The `IndexController` has the `setColor` action:

```
setColor: function(color) {
  this.set('color', color);
}
```

And the initial selection is set through this observer on the `ColorController`:

```
colorsChanged: function() {
  if (this.filterBy('isChecked', true).get('length') == 0) {
    var selectedColorId = this.parentController.get('model.color_id')+'',
        selectedColor = this.filterBy('id', selectedColorId);

    if (selectedColor.get('length') == 0) return;
    selectedColor.objectAt(0).set('isChecked', true);
  }
}.observes('this.[]')
```

This seems way too messy, but it also doesn't work 100%. For instance, a click on the radio button itself will actually un-check the radio button again.

Answer (score 1):

In Ember, things like radio buttons and checkboxes are best wrapped up in components. Unfortunately, a few edge cases have prevented Ember from shipping a radio button component as part of core.

The first thing I'd do is see if someone else has already implemented this. Are you using [Ember CLI](http://www.ember-cli.com)? If not, you should be. Browsing [Ember Addons](http://www.emberaddons.com) I find [two radio button components](http://www.emberaddons.com/#/?q=radio).

I'd give [ember-radio-button](https://github.com/yapplabs/ember-radio-button) a shot.

Comment: Thanks, I haven't prioritized looking into `ember-cli` just yet. I will look into `ember-radio-button` and get back tomorrow :-)